# How to end the load infile process in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, ctl

I am trying load the data using in ctl file , But  syntax error I am getting ,that is :SQL*Loader-350:   Syntax error at line 15.
 Expecting "," or ")", found keyword by.
 COS "TRUNC(:COS/32)",TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE
 following code is my try.

```
load data
INFILE 'rtd.txt'
INTO TABLE RTD_ATTLAS_TMP
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'
(
TRAFFIC_CUST_ID "UPPER(:TRAFFIC_CUST_ID)",
SOURCE_DEV_NAME "UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:SOURCE_DEV_NAME, '\\.\\D+', '', 1,  0))",
DEST_DEV_NAME "UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:DEST_DEV_NAME, '\\.\\D+', '', 1, 0))",
DATE_STAMP boundfiller,
TIME_STAMP "to_date(:DATE_STAMP ||' '|| :TIME_STAMP, 'mm/dd/yyyy   hh24:mi:ss')",
MIN_RTD,
AVG_RTD,
MAX_RTD,
COS "TRUNC(:COS/32)",TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE
)
```

Here is my file to be loaded 'rtd.txt':

```
NEW FEEDS TEST|ARAETSBUEAR01H03|172.20.227.220|10/08/2014|00:00:00|159|159|159|104
```

Comment: SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 15. Expecting "," or ")", found keyword by. COS "TRUNC(:COS/32)",TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE

Comment: What effect are you expecting the `,TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE` on line 15 to have? The comma is making it look like a new column called `TERMINATED` at the moment.

Comment: I want to end the process with WHITESPACE  after  COS "TRUNC(:COS/32)" column..

Comment: Is there more text after the value you want to interpret as `:COS`, or just a line break? If you just have whitespace up to the end of line  as you've shown (or next `|` separator) then you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: I have changed to  COS "TRUNC(:COS/32)" TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE    , but same error I am getting,

Comment: If I removed  "TRUNC(:COS/32)" from above statement , data is inserted properly, but that column value should be  TRUNC(:COS/32)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this in my code , it is working fine,

```
COS TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE  "TRUNC(:COS/32)"
```